# How to handle response from other akka actors effectively

Tags: java, akka

Consider this,

```
class PageActor extends UntypedActor {
private Page page;
private ActorRef documentActor;
public PDFPageActor(ActorRef pdfDocumentActor) {
    super();
    pdfPage = new PDFPage();
    this.pdfDocumentActor = pdfDocumentActor;
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    // handle the message;
}
public void doProcess() {
  statement;
  statement;
  send a request to **Document actor**(requesting a object);
  statement(make use of the above object);
  statement;
  send a request to **Document actor**(requesting a object);        
  statement(make use of above object);
  statement;
  statement(make use of both the objects)
}
}
```

If i use actorRef.tell(); it fires and forget.But what if we need the response from the **document actor** in the next subsequent steps , then one of the way to go is to use **ask** pattern.But **ask** pattern is blocking.Is there any other better way to tackle this.I went through other stack overflow answers,but didn't get a clear picture.

Any and all help is much appreciated

Comment: I disagree with your statement "But ask pattern is blocking."  From the doucmentation: "ask sends a message asynchronously and returns a Future representing a possible reply."  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/java/untyped-actors.html

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil    yeah i agree, but here [http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/java/futures.html] in the documentation it is described as blocking operation.Yeah we can overcome that with the **pipe** , but i was just looking for other ways.

Comment: The documentation you reference says the exact **opposite** of what you are claiming: "Using the ActorRef's ask method to send a message will return a Future. "  A Future, by definition, means that ask is **NOT BLOCKING**.

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil Sorry for the late reply.I accept ask returns a future, but it requires a timeout to be specified.Moreover i mentioned blocking , if i were to use **Await.result()** as a next statement to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the statements that depend on the "object" to the actor that controls/gets this object or a third  - "ProcessingActor".

It could look like this (the methods ar called on corresponding onReceive)

```
//in PageActor:
public void doProcess(){
   statement
   documentActor.tell(dataToProcess1, getSelf());
   documentActor.tell(dataToProcess2, getSelf());
}

//called from onReceive when processed data for an object is received
private void onDocumentProcessed(){
   if (all documents processed)
       process final statements
   else
       documents processed++;
}

//////////////////////////////////
//in DocumentActor:
      object = getObject(); //whatever that means in your application (probably blocking op)
      processingActor.forward(Message(object, dataToProcess));

/////////////////////////////////
//in ProcessingActor:
      statement(object); //execute statements that depend on the object
      getSender().tell(result, ActorRef.noSender()); //inform initial actor
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .... I actually implemented the same way as u proposed. Thought of implementing **Patterns.ask()** but it requires a timeout to be specified , hence i went with the other way around.